# Xcode breakpoints greyed out and not working

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I'm debugging an Objective-C app on the iPhone simulator. The app compiles and works. Xcode settings previously let me set debugger breakpoints and have the debugger actually break.

Now, the breakpoints show up in grey and the debugger doesn't stop on any breakpoint. Clicking on the breakpoint makes it light grey, but not blue like normal.

[image: This screenshot of Xcode shows the greyed out breakpoint.]

Can someone tell me which setting I need to revert to enable debugging again? Thanks.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Open your Debug Area:

[image]

Enable the `Breakpoint` and make it highlighted. BOOM!

Comment: @monkbroc the BLUE icon in my image.

Comment: Command + Y is shortcut to enable all breakpoints again ......@Wongzigii i Like Your BOOM! saved my time.

Answer (score 7):

In the top menu, open `Debug` and click `Activate breakpoints`. You can also use the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>  + <kbd>Y</kbd>.

Comment: Please edit your answer to small "y". Capital Y does something else.

Answer (score 3):

You should also be able to right click directly on the break point and choose "Enable Break Point" from the pop up menu.

OK...

You have all your breakpoints generally disabled.  This will gray out and ignore breakpoints even if they individually say they are enabled.

Go to the **Debug menu** in Xcode and select **Activate Breakpoints**.

Comment: The breakpoint is already enabled. If I right-click and select Disable breakpoint it becomes light grey. If I then select Enable breakpoint, it becomes dark grey, but doesn't get enabled.